# How to add radio button to RadioGroup with dynamic data in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

I have an issue when adding Radio Button to RadioGroup with dynamic data.

In detail as below:

```
private fun initRadioButton(){
        val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group)
        radioGroup.orientation=LinearLayout.VERTICAL

        val setValueRadioButton:RadioButton.(Student)-> Unit ={ student->
            text= student.name
            id= View.generateViewId()
            tag= student
        }

        datas.map {
            val rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button_item,null) as LinearLayout
            val rdStudent = rootView.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.rd_student)
            rdStudent.setValueRadioButton(it)
            radioGroup.addView(rdStudent)
        }

    }
```

and XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

and radio button item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rd_student"
        android:text="kskkss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I thought everything was fine until I ran it but it throws an exception as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

So anyone helps me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  I'm not entire sure what you're trying to do, but for sure the error is correct. You should add your RadioButton in the RadioGroup in the XML.  You could set the RadioGroup (or radio button) background color to black.  This allows you to remove your RadioButtonItem XML.  You could also play with the visibility of the button, according to your needs.

You can also create a radio button widget dynamically, then add it to the radio group dynamically.

Good luck!